# Very strange; containing element changes size when $(this).width() is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on making a navigation bar at the bottom of the webpage (for mobile layouts), and I use jQuery to resize the navigation after the page has loaded.

I have each button as a cell in a table , and each cell contains an image.  I'm trying to set the image dimensions based on the size of the  element.  What I have now works exactly like I want it, but I don't know why.

The source of my confusion:

```
$("img.nav").each(function() {
    $(this).width(); // commenting out this line changes the width of each <td> element     
    $(this).css("display", "block");
    $(this).css("height", "80%");
    $(this).css("width", "auto");
});
```

Here's what I get when I print the td's width:

With $(this).width(); as is:

```
w 0: 217
w 1: 217
w 2: 217
```

Which is perfect. Here's the output when I comment out that line:

```
w 0: 210
w 1: 200
w 2: 241
```

Not perfect. I need them all to be the same.

E: Also, removing the "display: none;" line in the CSS file simulates the same problem.

Here's the rest of my code (it's short):

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/globals.css" />

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libjs.js"></script>

        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content"><p>Some example text that does nothing.</p></div>

        <nav>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td id="nav_home" class="active">
                        <img class="center nav" src="img/home.png" alt="img_nav_home" width="150" height="200"/>
                    </td>

                    <td id="nav_map">
                        <img class="center nav" src="img/map.png" alt="img_nav_map" width="103" height="200"/>
                    </td>

                    <td id="nav_send">
                        <img class="center nav" src="img/send.png" alt="img_nav_send" width="286" height="200"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* 
{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-style: none;
    font-family: "Berlin Sans FB", Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #383c47;

    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);  /* transparent link selection, last value opacity 0 to 1.0 */
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;                    /* prevent callout to copy image */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;                 /* prevent resizing text to fit */
    -webkit-user-select: none;                      /* prevent copy paste */
}

/* Centers an image both horizontally and vertically in it's container. */
img.center {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

body {
    background-image: url(../img/bg.png); 
}

#content {
    background-color: white;
    width: 70%;
    height: 70%;
}

    #content p {
        padding: 5%;
    }

/* The navigation bar at the bottom of each page. */
nav {
    background-color: #b50043;
    width: 100%;
    height: 18%;
}

    nav table {
        border-spacing: 0px;
    }

    nav table .active {
        background-color: #383c47;
    }

    nav table img.nav {     
        display: none;  /* Also, removing this line will cause the same problem */
    }

    nav table #nav_home {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }

    nav table #nav_map {
        background-color: green;
    }

    nav table #nav_send {
        background-color: blue;
    }
```

jQuery:

```
// Centers the element both vertically and horizontally in the given element.
// Allows Top and Left offsets to account for "fixed" elements in the parent.
// Does not work with images (images work a little differently).
jQuery.fn.center = function(parent, offsetTop, offsetLeft) {
    $(this).css("position", "absolute");
    $(this).css("top", ($(parent).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2 + offsetTop);
    $(this).css("left", ($(parent).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2 + offsetLeft);

    return $(this);
}

// Use .resize and .ready to adjust layout based on screen size
$(window).resize(function() {
    $("#content").center($(window), -($("nav").height() / 2), 0);

    // positions the navigation bar at the bottom of the page
    $("nav").css("position", "fixed");
    $("nav").css("top", $(window).height() - $("nav").height());

    // equally distribute nav buttons over the width of the screen
    $("nav table tr > td").each(function() {
        $(this).width($("nav").width() / $(this).length);
        $(this).height($("nav").height());
    }); 

    $("img.nav").each(function() {
        //$(this).width();          
        $(this).css("display", "block");
        $(this).css("height", "80%");
        $(this).css("width", "auto");
    });

    $("td").each(function(i) {
        console.log("w " + i + ": " + $(this).width());
    })

});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That shouldn't happen, I'm guessing wildly that you're not waiting for the images to load, and that call to .width() somehow takes enough time that the images will be loaded or something like that.

Comment: But don't the images load before jQuery's .ready event is fired?  That .width() call is only called after the page has loaded.

Comment: Nope, the DOM is ready on document.ready, there's no guarantee that the images have loaded.

Comment: Interesting. So how would I wait until the images have loaded?

Comment: You should use $(window).load instead of document.ready

Comment: And you really shouldn't be using tables for layout...

Comment: I only use a table for the navigation bar, not the entire layout. What's the harm in that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by using

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

to evenly distribute the table cells rather than calculating it on page load. Not sure why I didn't think of this before.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your call resize on on `$(window).load` instead of `$(document).ready`.

The problem is in next thing - **`document.ready`** event is fired when when **HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready** but you need to **wait until all images are loaded** as well.

**Documentation:**

[**onload Event**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)

[**ready Event**](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_ready.asp)

Comment: Thanks, but the same thing still happens. :(  All I changed was $(document).ready() to $(window).load().